# Remove Object from Array of Object in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, sorting

I have this type of JSON and what I want, to remove the complete object of **StartGeotag** from array of object.

```
[{
    CreatedDate: "2022-02-17T10:30:07.0442288Z"
    DeletedDate: null ProjectId: "05b76d03-8c4b-47f4-7c20-08d9e2990812"
    StartGeotag: {
        Type: 'Point',
        Latitude: '33.6607231',
        CreatedDate: '2022-02- :34:46.5389961Z'
    }
    StartTime: "2022-02-17T10:30:05.828Z"
}]
```

Comment: Please show us how you have attempted to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using ES6 Spread Operator you can achieve this:
Whatever you want to remove, give that key in argument, and `...rest` will return the rest arguments.

```js
var data = [{ CreatedDate: "2022-02-17T10:30:07.0442288Z", 
DeletedDate: null, 
ProjectId: "05b76d03-8c4b-47f4-7c20-08d9e2990812",
StartGeotag: {Type: 'Point', Latitude: '33.6607231', 
CreatedDate: '2022-02- :34:46.5389961Z'},
StartTime: "2022-02-17T10:30:05.828Z"}]

const res= data.map(({StartGeotag, ...rest}) => ({...rest})); 

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from [ES6](http://es6-features.org/).

**Working Demo :**

```js
let jsonObj = [{
    CreatedDate: "2022-02-17T10:30:07.0442288Z",
    DeletedDate: null,
    ProjectId: "05b76d03-8c4b-47f4-7c20-08d9e2990812",
    StartGeotag: {
        Type: 'Point',
        Latitude: '33.6607231',
        CreatedDate: '2022-02- :34:46.5389961Z'
    },
    StartTime: "2022-02-17T10:30:05.828Z"
}];

let res = jsonObj.map(({StartGeotag, ...remainingItems}) => remainingItems)

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by destructuring your object.

```
[{ CreatedDate: "2022-02-17T10:30:07.0442288Z" , DeletedDate: null, ProjectId: "05b76d03-8c4b-47f4-7c20-08d9e2990812",
    StartGeotag: {Type: 'Point', Latitude: '33.6607231', CreatedDate: '2022-02- :34:46.5389961Z'},
    StartTime: "2022-02-17T10:30:05.828Z"}].map(({StartGeotag, ...item}) => item)
```

If you want to take only the StartGeoTag object than you can do it in this way:

```
 [{ CreatedDate: "2022-02-17T10:30:07.0442288Z" , DeletedDate: null, ProjectId: "05b76d03-8c4b-47f4-7c20-08d9e2990812",
    StartGeotag: {Type: 'Point', Latitude: '33.6607231', CreatedDate: '2022-02- :34:46.5389961Z'},
    StartTime: "2022-02-17T10:30:05.828Z"}].map(({StartGeotag}) => StartGeotag)
```